# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags - but regex101.com says my regex is OK?

Tags: javascript

I have a regex which is working according to regex101.com, however when I use it in my JS I get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags

const bandsReduced = bands.map((item)=>{
  return item.replace(/the|a/gAi,'');
});
```

Comment: `A` is not a flag specified in JavaScript, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Seems like you forgot to select the "javascript" flavor on regex101.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `A` is not a flag in JavaScript.

Valid flags are `g`,`i`, `m`, `u`, `y`. See the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Different languages have slightly different regex syntax, in [regex101](https://regex101.com/) you can change the language as per image below.

[image]

*(as mentioned by elcanrs in the comment)*

Answer (score 1):

The ^ character is used in JavaScript to limit the search to the beginning of the string:

```
const bandsReduced = bands.map((item)=>{
  return item.replace(/^the|^a/ig,'');
});
```